# Getting sum of amounts from firestore

Tags: flutter

```
    class totalDS extends StatefulWidget {
  const totalDS({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _totalDSState createState() => _totalDSState();
}

double _total = 0.00;

class _totalDSState extends State<totalDS> {
  Future getTotal() async {
    final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('DailySale').get();

    _firestore.then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
            for (var i = 1; i < element.data().length; i++) {
              _total = _total + element.data()['invAmountDS'];
            }
          })
        });
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text('$_total'.toString()));
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ynk8.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODvfM.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YWzb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lLRw.png)

I m getting the sum as 0.0

anybody can help me regarding this?
i want to display total sum of the invoices.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  final myList = [1, 3, 5, 8, 7, 2, 11];
  final result = myList.fold(0, (sum, element) => sum + element);
  
  print(result);
}
```

Use Fold Method

Answer (score 0):

In code you provided, you never even call `getTotal()` function. You can call it in `initState()` method like this:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getTotal();
}
```

And you should also add `setState()` function after you finish your for loop

```dart
for (var i = 1; i < element.data().length; i++) {
  _total = _total + element.data()['invAmountDS'];
}
setState((){});
```

This will make the widget to rebuild when the function counted `_total` value

Comment: Yes, that was true. I was getting Zero all the time. btw. Thanks problemed solved. It is the same for loop code. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is best method to add ,

```
var sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

but if the list is empty than to handle this empty condition we prefer  `fold()` over `.reduce()`

```
int sum = [1, 2, 3].fold(0, (a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: The ```.reduce()```part is for knowledge purpose!!!